# angular2 [innerHTML] not working properly with ionic <ion-list>

Tags: html, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

I am using ionic 3 and angular 2 and I have ran into a problem with [innerHTML] styling a big html string. While it is working fine in a div tag standing alone, it cuts off the string at the end of the screen istead of going to the next line when in an ion-list tag. Any idea why is this happening?
Images and code below:
[Within a div tag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hlrH0.png). 
[Withing an ion-list tag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jeTyb.png)

**Html file with div tag**

```
  <button (click)="this.getSchoolInfo(16329)" > Load string </button>
  <div [innerHTML] = "test"> </div>
```

**Html file with ion-list tag**

```
<ion-list-header> Σχολές </ion-list-header>
<ion-item *ngFor="let i of schools" (click)="toggleDetails(i.school)">
  <b>{{i.school.title}}</b><br>


  <div class="info" *ngIf="i.school.showDetails" [innerHTML]="test"></div>

</ion-item>
```

**Big string at .ts file**

```
  this.test = "<p>bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbgggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggg</p>"
```

Comment: Have you tried with adding some spaces inside the string?

Comment: Yeap. It doesnt changes anything http://prntscr.com/ggv8aq

Comment: I'd suggest you inspect the styles in chrome devtools and disable them until you find out which one causes it, and then overrule this style from your code.

Comment: Probably the ion-item has a css rule of `text-overflow: hidden;` or something like that

Comment: Why do you use innerHTML and not {{test}} or ionic not able to resolve that?

Comment: @devqon already tried that but does not work...

Comment: @MeMeMax using {{test}} would output the string with all the html tags ( <p> in my case ) as simple text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your problem is related to **text-wrap** class. I am also facing this problem. here is my code. You can be modified according to your need.

syntax with **text-wrap**

```
<ion-list text-wrap *ngFor="let post of newsData">
<hr>
<ion-item (click)="NewsDetailsPage(post.news_id);" detail-push>

<ion-thumbnail item-start>
  <img [src]="post.news_photo">
</ion-thumbnail>
<h2>{{post.news_heading}}</h2>
<div><p style="float: left; font-weight: normal; font-size: 12px;"> {{post.news_location}}</p>
<p style="float: right; margin-top: 1%; font-weight: normal;  font-size: 12px;">{{post.news_date | date: 'dd/MM/yyyy' }}</p></div>

</ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

**Output:**
[image]

Without **text-wrap** the output is like that:

[image]

> I hope this will help you.